# I have a datatable in Javascript and (almost) everything works fine, but i don't know how to refer to a value in the same row...any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Basically, I have a button in every row in the third column, and when the user clicks on the button, I would like to call a function with parameters (they are from the table row). I saw that someone use row.errorType (for example), but that's gave me 'undefined' value :( Any ideas?

```
            columns: [
                {
                    "data": "errorType",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "errorDescription",
                    "render": function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "entityId",
                    "render": function (data, row) {
                        return `<button class="newError" onclick="openModal(${row.errorType}, ${row.errorDescription}, ${data})"><i class="icon ticket errorTableIcon"></i></button>`;
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Comment: What library are you using for this table?  I'm guessing there is documentation on it...unless you/your team wrote it, then you're on your own

Comment: one way to find out what data your column is receiving is put a `console.log` in your onclick handler and just see what the parameters coming contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the DataTables [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option, but you are not supplying the expected parameters.

You are using:

```
"render": function (data, row) { ... }
```

You should be using:

```
"render": function (data, type, row, meta) { ... }
```

So, what you are referring to as `row` is actually `type`. Change your parameters as shown above to pick up the `row` data object correctly - and then you should be able to use variables such as `row.errorType` in your string builder.

---

You still need to ensure that variables which resolve to strings are themselves enclosed in quotes, so your string template may need to be adjusted.

For example, you may need `"${row.errorDescription}"` instead of `${row.errorDescription}`.